# Service with both selector and explicit endpoints?

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery

As part of a migration from a legacy service discovery framework to kube/CoreDNS I would like to create a Service that knows how auto-publish `Endpoints`, but *also* have manually created endpoints.

Essentially I think I would like the following:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    transition: legacy
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 1.2.3.4
  ports:
  - port: 9376
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-discovery-backend
  labels:
    app: MyApp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: MyApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: MyApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

As [the docs imply](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), though, explicitly setting things up like this results in there only being one Endpoints object associated with the service -- whether it's the service's auto-created one or my manually specified one seems to vary.

Is the most reasonable way to use CoreDNS as service discovery for both services that know how to self-publish and external services to manually control endpoints until we are 100% migrated, and then just switch over to a selector-based approach?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using just Kubernetes Service, but I see one workaround here.

I believe, you can use additional Service backed by Nginx Pod (or deployment), manually configured (by config-map) as a reverse proxy for two backends: Kubernetes Service name (with selector, for new backend) and a manual endpoint (fqdn or IP, for legacy backend).

```
ingress -> Service1 -> Nginx--> Service2 -> Deployments/Pods
                          | 
                           ---> Endpoint -> Legacy Servers
```

It's up to you how to [balance](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/configure-load-balancing-nginx/) traffic to between them.